# Why is my dSLR not capturing images and lagging?

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, performance

I have a Nikon D3500 I’ve been using since 2020. I would say the past 6 months it has been super laggy; I have reset my settings multiple times, charged batteries, and cleared memory cards.

It first started with not capturing the imaging a lot even when in good natural lighting. Then when I go to view images it will take a while to open that setting up to even view them and then go through the images. Super annoying when shooting for a client. Any feedback would be great.

Answer (score 9):

First test, throw away all your old cards & buy new ones. From your symptom description is it far more likely to be a card [or potentially contacts] issue than camera.
SD cards are far from indestructible. They get sector errors which will slow down read/write operations.

Comment: I agree that you probably need new cards, but before even that, try *formatting* them *in the camera*, not just deleting all the images.  This should show some improvement and will also test the cards

Comment: @ChrisH - I used to get through literally thousands of these for work. I developed a hearty distain for them over time, & first sign of trouble, in the bin they went. They're usually not worth fighting once they start to go. I agree it's worth one shot at a format in-camera, but how much would you trust one that was already getting bad sectors, especially for irreplaceable images? First time you get a real write error, the firmware lock will kick in & you might spend the rest of the day shooting to a card that's not actually writing data any more, just 'pretending' to.

Comment: Bad sectors or read/write errors are for the bin, that's for sure. But heavily used cards can develop slowness that's not necessarily due to bad sectors.  And a work budget  changes the calculations a bit too (it may apply to the OP more than to me).  The failure modes I've seen (on Canon) don't seem to lead to fake writes, but are more obvious.  You'd lose a burst at most.  Video is of course more demandi9ng

Comment: If the problem is the mem card, perhaps shooting in burst mode will tell, because it stores images in an internal buffer (I think). If burst works (all shots end up ok and at the right timing), but _then_ writing lags, then mem card is seriously suspect.